# Unable to connect from Power BI to Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, m, powerbi-datasource

I am trying the Power BI with the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powerbi-visualize#prerequisites

Trying to connect to the demo DB (URL: https://analytics.documents.azure.com) I get the error:
Details: "The specified database was not found."

Answer (score 3):

The [workaround](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Document-DB-Power-BI/idi-p/208200) is to start with an empty query and enter the formula manually:

```
let
    Source = DocumentDB.Contents("https://analytics.documents.azure.com", null, null)
in
    Source
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Ok, I got the list of tables, what should I do next - to do analytics on the volcano db.

Comment: And how come I dont need to put in the key to the DB?

Comment: @SarahSh Just click the `Table` to drill down on the `volcanodb` and start from there. You don't need to input the key (again) because the credential is already stored in `Data Source Settings` in Power BI Desktop in your previous trials.

Comment: Hi @SarahSh does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. BUT, I found a workaround to get connected to my Cosmos DB from Power BI Desktop using "Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB ODBC driver" for windows.

Reference article on odbc driver: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver).

Comment: Please provide the content of the link here as well. Links may die over time and we would like to preserve the content.